# TSQL - Faster to use IN (list) or use NOT IN (list) for a small list?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlperformance, notin, sql-in

One of my columns can only contain 4 possible values (`val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`).

I need to add an additional filter in the `WHERE` clause to exlude one of those 4 values (i.e. `val4`).

Is it going to be faster to use `NOT IN ('val4')` or `IN ('val1','val2','val3')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOT IN ('val4')` is basically equivalent to

```
WHERE
    NOT (column = 'val4') /* or column <> 'val4' */
```

whereas `IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` is basically equivalent to

```
WHERE
(
   column = 'val1'
   OR
   column = 'val2'
   OR 
   column = 'val3'
)
```

I would hope that the first option is faster, if only negligibly. The SQL engine might optimize `IN` differently depending on how many values you specify in the `IN` function and what indexes are available on your table. What behavior are you seeing that you're questioning the method to use?

Comment: I would have normally just used a `!=`, but thought I had read around (on SO) that it's not always the best option and can cause performance issues.

Comment: what you said makes sense though. Just looking for any additional insight I might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the query plan.  If Val4 is non clustered index I bet both plans are an index seek.
I tested in, not in, =, and <> and all were the same query plan.
If they have the same query plan I doubt the actual performance difference would be big enough to see.  But I would still go with the single value.

Since there are only a few values an indexed view would probably have the best performance.